# Need to combine 2 query into 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to combine this 2 query into 1. Can someone help me please?

Query 1:

```
SELECT
    Date_Consommation AS Date_Consommation, 
    Odometre AS Odometre,   
    IDProduits AS IDProduits,   
    IDZ_Consommations_Provenances AS IDZ_Consommations_Provenances, 
    IDEmployes AS IDEmployes,   
    IDFournisseurs AS IDFournisseurs
FROM 
    Consommations
WHERE IDVehicules = 3140
AND Date_Consommation <= '20191114'
ORDER BY Date_Consommation DESC, Odometre DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
    Odometre AS maxOdo
FROM
    Consommations
WHERE IDVehicules = 3140
AND Date_Consommation >= '20191114'
ORDER BY Date_Consommation, Odometre
LIMIT 1
```

Here are the data for example and what I want as result:
[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWj2v.png)

```
The result I want is:
Date_Consommation = 2019-11-12
Odometre = 221698
IDProduits = 342412 
IDZ_Cons... = 16
IDEmployes = 10 
IDFournisseurs = 3
maxOdo = 222354
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Explain what *you* mean by combining the queries.

Comment: You should provide more explanation on what you mean by combine. If you would like to see both results one below the other, then you could use either the union command or the union all, depening on whether you want duplicates or not. But this requires both queries to have the same column names in the same order

Comment: Have you tried Union?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I always got an error message, I cannot run the query. From what I understand, I must have the same columns in the 2 queries and I am also unable to place correctly my "order by" clauses that are different from one query to another.

Comment: `SELECT
    NULL,
    Odometre ,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
FROM
    Consommations
WHERE IDVehicules = 3140
AND Date_Consommation >= '20191114'
ORDER BY Date_Consommation, Odometre
LIMIT 1`
can you try this with `Union`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all your help, here's how I did to get what I wanted!

```
SELECT
    bloc1.Date_Consommation,
    bloc1.Odometre,
    bloc1.IDProduits,
    bloc1.IDZ_Consommations_Provenances,
    bloc1.IDEmployes,
    bloc1.IDFournisseurs,
    bloc2.maxOdo
FROM
    (SELECT
        Date_Consommation,
        Odometre,
        IDProduits,
        IDZ_Consommations_Provenances,
        IDEmployes,
        IDFournisseurs
    FROM Consommations
    WHERE IDVehicules = 3140
    AND Date_Consommation <= '20191114'
    ) bloc1,

    (SELECT MAX(Odometre) AS maxOdo
    FROM Consommations
    WHERE IDVehicules = 3140
    AND Date_Consommation >= '20191114'
    ) bloc2

ORDER BY Date_Consommation DESC, Odometre DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database allows a CTE, then, that would be one way.  you would need to add IDvehicules to the output from each query and then join the two queries on IDvehicules.  Also, since you are limiting the output to one row, there is no need for an order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible to use cross join (or maybe inner join `ON C1.IDVehicules = C2.IDVehicules`) to the same table and select required data, here is the SQL, but it is not tested in any way.

```
SELECT
    C1.Date_Consommation AS Date_Consommation, 
    C1.Odometre AS Odometre,   
    C1.IDProduits AS IDProduits,   
    C1.IDZ_Consommations_Provenances AS IDZ_Consommations_Provenances, 
    C1.IDEmployes AS IDEmployes,   
    C1.IDFournisseurs AS IDFournisseurs
    C2.Odometre AS maxOdo
FROM 
    Consommations C1
    CROSS JOIN Consommations C2 
WHERE C1.IDVehicules = 3140 AND C2.IDVehicules = 3140
    AND C1.Date_Consommation <= '20191114' AND C2.Date_Consommation >= '20191114'
ORDER BY C1.Date_Consommation DESC, C1.Odometre DESC, C2.Date_Consommation, C2.Odometre
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes the query works but returns nothing... thanks for your help!